# Scala - [T <: SomeClass] vs someThing +: SomeClass

Tags: scala

What is the diffrence between [T <: SomeClass]  vs [T +: SomeClass].

someThing +: SomeClass : I understand like, someThing might be same SomeClass or any sub class of SomeClass.
[T <: SomeClass] : I don't have any idea.

Please clear my doubt please.

Comment: Well, one of them is invalid Scala syntax.. did you mean to write something different than `[T +: SomeClass]`?

Comment: Yeah, agree with @MichaelZajac. There's the `<:` operator, which is only used for types and can only be used inside a set of generics brackets. Then there's the `+:` method that a lot of collections define. It allows you to add something to the beginning of the collection. t +: listOfT is the same as listOfT.+:(t). For example, `"a" +: List("b", "c")` should produce `List("a", "b", "c")`.

Comment: There is also `[T : SomeTypeClass]` which is a syntax sugar for `[T]...(implicit foo: SomeTypeClass[T])`